# std::shared_ptr Deletor Type

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, shared-ptr

I'm getting strange errors trying to pass a custom deletor to std::shared_ptr:

```
std::shared_ptr<unsigned char*> SDLWindow::drawGrid(const Grid* grid) { 
    SDL_Surface* rgbSurface = SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat(surface, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB888, 0);
    //...error checking and locking the SDL_Surface, omitted for brevity
    unsigned char* pixelsPtr = (unsigned char*)(rgbSurface->pixels);

    //need a custom deleter because we created a copy of the SDL_Surface
    //we cant directly delete the pixel data but need to delete the underlying SDL_Surface instead
    auto surfaceDeleter = [rgbSurface](decltype(pixelsPtr)* ignored) 
            //don't directly delete the pixel buffer, delete the underlying SDL_Surface instead
            {
                //unlock the surface if necessary
                if(SDL_MUSTLOCK(rgbSurface))
                {
                    SDL_UnlockSurface(rgbSurface);
                }
                SDL_FreeSurface(rgbSurface);
            };
    return std::shared_ptr<unsigned char*>(pixelsPtr, surfaceDeleter);
}
```

(I changed `const unsigned char*` -> `unsigned char*` in case that had anything to do with it but I would prefer to use const if possible)

Clang says something about not being able to convert to `nullptr_t`, which I assume is related to how shared_ptrs use type erasure (but why shouldn't they be able to handle pointers?)

```
    unsigned char* pixelsPtr = (unsigned char*)(rgbSurface->pixels);
[..]/src/SDLWindow.cpp:132:12: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::shared_ptr<unsigned char *>'
    return std::shared_ptr<unsigned char*>(pixelsPtr, surfaceDeleter);
           ^                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:3809:26: note: candidate constructor [with _Dp = (lambda at
      /[..]/src/SDLWindow.cpp:122:27)] not viable: no known conversion from 'unsigned char *' to 'nullptr_t' for 1st argument
    template <class _Dp> shared_ptr(nullptr_t __p, _Dp __d);
```

Oddly g++ seems to give a completely different error:

```
                 from /[..]/src/SDLWindow.hpp:4,
                 from /[..]/src/SDLWindow.cpp:1:
/opt/local/include/gcc49/c++/bits/shared_ptr_base.h: In instantiation of 'std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::__shared_ptr(_Tp1*, _Deleter) [with _Tp1 = unsigned char; _Deleter = jakway_antf::SDLWindow::drawGrid(const jakway_antf::Grid*)::<lambda(unsigned char**)>; _Tp = unsigned char*; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2u]':
/opt/local/include/gcc49/c++/bits/shared_ptr.h:130:37:   required from 'std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(_Tp1*, _Deleter) [with _Tp1 = unsigned char; _Deleter = jakway_antf::SDLWindow::drawGrid(const jakway_antf::Grid*)::<lambda(unsigned char**)>; _Tp = unsigned char*]'
/[..]/src/SDLWindow.cpp:132:69:   required from here
/opt/local/include/gcc49/c++/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:881:37: error: cannot convert 'unsigned char*' to 'unsigned char**' in initialization
  : _M_ptr(__p), _M_refcount(__p, ntf::SDLWindow::drawGrid(const jakway_antf::))
```

With regards to g++ I don't know what's going on because I've messed with the parameter to the lambda and declaring it `unsigned char**` doesn't do anything.

I've tried:

- messing with the capture parameter, which didn't seem to do anything (from what I remember from a couple hours ago)
- casting every which way
- declaring the lambda with std::function instead of auto
  and am quite stuck.

Comment: I believe `std::shared_ptr<unsigned char*>` should be `std::shared_ptr<unsigned char>`

Comment: @NathanOliver Yikes, I really should have caught that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a much cleaner way to do what you want, using an awesome and very under-documented feature of shared pointers:

```
// 1
std::shared_ptr<SDL_Surface> surface_ptr {
    SDL_ConvertSurfaceFormat(surface, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB888, 0),
    [](SDL_Surface* p) {
        if(SDL_MUSTLOCK(p))
            SDL_UnlockSurface(p);
        SDL_FreeSurface(p);
    }
};

// 2
std::shared_ptr<unsigned char> pixels = { surface_ptr, surface->pixels };
```

line 1 allocates the surface and puts it under the control of a shared pointer with a custom deleter.

line 2 is the awesome part. It initialises a shared pointer to point to the pixel data while using the *same control block* as the surface.

This means that the surface will be deleted only when both shared pointers have been destroyed or reset. It is the control block which holds the reference counts and the deleter, so you don't have to be concerned that the two shared pointers point to different types - the second is merely a convenient facade of the first.

Note that you don't have to capture anything in the lambda - shared_ptr does this for you and passes the surface address as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

`std::shared_ptr<unsigned char*>` should be `std::shared_ptr<unsigned char>`.  Using `std::shared_ptr<unsigned char*>` means the underlying pointer is an `unsigned char**` as `shared_ptr<T>` stores a `T*`.  Since you have an `unsigned char*` we want `T` to be a `unsigned char`